I would like to know can this company do this?
Has anyone ever heard of Hcrex? I invested 1000 and profit 10,000. When I went to withdraw some of the funds I was told I had to pay 3000 in tax before I can withdraw anything.

Hi William, it’s a common scam to ask for an advance fee. If they actually had 10,000 they could just keep 3000 for the tax. So they probably don’t have 10,000 in your name.
